# Why can't I orderBy() on eager-loaded relationship with constraints?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, eager-loading

```
$Classes = Classes::with(['Queue' => function($query){

    $query->where('date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse("2018-09-16"))
          ->where('status', ClassStatus::PENDING())
          ->orderBy('date', 'asc');

}])->whereIn('user_course_id', UserCourse::get_user_course_id($user_id))->get();
```

This is the query I'm using to get my $Classes.

I later display my 'Queue' data using

```
   foreach($Queues as $Queue){
               foreach($Queue as $Q){
                echo $Q->date."\n";
               }

        }
```

The output I'm getting is

```
2018-09-16
2018-09-13
2018-09-12
2018-09-13
2018-09-13
```

So it's definitely ordering by the 'Queue' model `id`. How can I order by the `date` column instead?

Comment: what is the type of date field in database?

Comment: You can add `->orderBy(...);` in the relationship defined in your model.

Comment: @Jinal, it's a DATETIME field. It seems to be ordering correctly when I run a normal query

Comment: @Chin, I'll try that and update my post if it helps me achieve the desired effect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ordering the queues *per* class. Use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby):

```
$Queues = $Queues->sortBy('date');
```

Comment: I haven't got sortBy() to work, but that actually identifies my problem. Thank you.